# .Net in HTML to return true if reader object not null, otherwise return false

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm using a DataList to show some data from the database and populating the fields on the html side. I now have a requirement to change the visibility of a panel based on whether or not a db field has data or not.

I need to be able to show the panel if the relevant data field has content, and hide it if it doesn't. Eg:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlNew" runat="server" Style="margin:0; padding:0; width:42px; height:18px; bottom:5px; right:10px; float:right; position:relative; background:url(../_imgVideoBadge.png) no-repeat;" Visible='<%# Eval("cheese") != null %>' ToolTip="available"></asp:Panel>
```

Obviously this doesn't work in terms of the visible property. But hopefully it gives an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've seen examples previously of doing something along the lines of:

```
    a ?? b:c
```

How could this be applied to the above requirement??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I managed to work out:

```
    (Eval("cheese").ToString().Trim() == String.Empty) ? false : true
```

As it seems the result was an empty string rather than a null.

Answer (score 2):

`Visible='<%# Information.IsDBNull(Eval("cheese")) %>'` should return a boolean.

Comment: Thanks for the response but what does the 'Information' pertain to?

Comment: It's a built-in class containing several static helper methods. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/428tfy8s.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)          
        SqlConnection MyConnection;
        SqlCommand MyCommand;
        SqlDataReader MyReader;
        MyConnection = new SqlConnection();
        MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

        MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
        MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 10 * From PRODUCTS";
        MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

        MyCommand.Connection.Open();
        MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        if (MyReader != null)
        {
            datalist1.DataSource = MyReader;
            datalist1.DataBind();
            pnlNew.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            pnlNew.Visible = false;
        }
        MyCommand.Dispose();
        MyConnection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. That really doesnt answer the question. The point is to do this on the html side.

Comment: Okay, will also try it from HTML side for sure.

Comment: That is codebehind! You wouldnt do that in html unless you were very odd.